# xpath remove an attribute from an dynamic attribute list

Tags: xpath

I want remove an xml attribute via xpath, but 
the xml element could have more atrributes in the future.

```
html code:
    <p class="red, blue, green">test/<p>

xpath: 
    <xpath expr="//p[contains(@class, 'green')]" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="class">red, blue</attribute>
    </xpath>
```

Is where a better way for fixtext "red, blue"?

In  order to suppport possible new version of the html file like
`"<p class="red, blue, green, brown">test</p>"` in the future without need to change the xpath code again.

for instance actual attribute list as var + an xpath function

Comment: Just an aside, usually classes in html aren't separated by comma, just by whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting the @class to

```
concat(substring-before(@class, "green"), substring-after(@class, "green"))
```

You'll need to solve the abandoned commas, too, but as Björn Tantau commented, in real HTML the classes would be separated by spaces, so you can just wrap the result into `normalize-space`.

Comment: Thanks red, blue, green was a typo, i meant  "red blue green"